# React: Did not parse stylesheet at {{URL}} because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode & SyntaxError: Unexpected Token '<'

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am deploying a React app to Heroku and although the build succeeds, what I get in the browser is a blank page and a few errors in the console. I am using the Brad Traversy ProShop tutorial https://github.com/bradtraversy/proshop_mern as a reference.

In Safari:

- Did not parse stylesheet at '.../static/css/main.466da7d4.chunk.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.
- SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
- SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

In Google Chrome:

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
- Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

This is my manifest.json file:

```
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

This is my server.js file:

```
import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
import colors from "colors";
import { notFound, errorHandler } from "./middleware/errorMiddleware.js";
import productRoutes from "./routes/productRoutes.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import orderRoutes from "./routes/orderRoutes.js";
import uploadRoutes from "./routes/uploadRoutes.js";

dotenv.config();

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/products", productRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/orders", orderRoutes);
app.use("/api/upload", uploadRoutes);

app.get("/api/config/paypal", (req, res) => {
  res.send(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);
});

const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/uploads")));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {

  app.use(
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/frontend/build"))
  );

  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "build", "index.html")
    )
  );

  
} else {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API is running....");
  });
}

app.use(notFound);

app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  )
);
```

Comment: are you missing the starting braces in the original manifest file as well or you mistyped it here ?

Comment: I mistyped, sorry...I just checked and I have starting braces. Thank you!